# Why isn't my Python 'Task' class useful?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to learn how to use python classes to make my code more elegant. I've written code that works, however I don't see why classes are useful. I have a feeling that I'm using classes wrong. I created a class object and inside I have three methods (`create`, `remove`, and `update`). My class is called `Task`. I would like to use classes to call my functions, like how we use a module.

Here is my code so far:

```
class Task(object):

    def __init__(self):
        return None

    def create(self):
        client.hr.post_job(owner,title,rate,description,private_or_not,category,sub_category,budget, skills = ['data-mining','data-scraping','google-docs','google-spreadsheet','internet-research','spreadsheets'])
        print "Job successfully created!"

    def remove(self):
        client.hr.remove_job(job_key)
    def update(self):
        client.hr.update_job(job_key)



main = Task()
main.list_jobs()
```

Comment: instead of main.list_jobs(), it's main.create()

Comment: In addition to @Benji's point, where does your `client` variable come from?

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas I'm working with the API, client = upwork.Client(key,secret)

Comment: @Benji: You should correct mistakes in the question directly,  not in the comments.  There's an "edit" button right under the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is relatively simple: you are not keeping any 'state' in your class `Task`. Each method in `Task` is operating in a 'functional' paradigm: that is, all the data it is operating on is passed directly to the function. In an object-oriented approach, some of the data would be held by the class itself.

Were you setting data in your `__init__`, or keeping data around between method calls, your use of the class to structure your codebase would make more sense.

There are some obvious use cases for using a class: for instance, when working with a database, a 'database object relational mapping object' typically 'remembers' the database. This way you can update the information in the database without needing to pass the database to the function doing the information update every single time. This is, of course, just one of an uncountable number of ways you could use class data effectively.

For instance, let's say I want to have an employee:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name: str, years_of_employment: int):
        self.name = name
        self.years_of_employment = years_of_employment

    def to_string(self) -> str:
        return "{} has worked here {} years".format(self.name, self.years_of_employment)
```

Then, later:

```
e = Employee("Bob", 2)
print(e.to_string())  //to_string remembers the name and years of employment
```

If these concepts are new, read up on [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). An 'Object' is a *specific instantiation* of a 'Class' of objects, meant to hold 'state' and describe 'behavior'. So, in the example above, `e` is a specific instantiation of the class `Employee`. The object `e` holds the 'state' describing the `name` and `years_of_employment` of the object `e`. `e` can be easily passed around, and behavior that depends on the 'state' of `e` can be called directly: in this case the `to_string` method describes behavior whenever you need to get a string representing the object `e` by returning a properly formatted string that includes state values of `e`.

Comment: The return value is not the issue. It's the state you save on the object itself. Do you understand 'state' and 'objects', and how they relate? If not that may be at the core of your misapprehension.

Comment: I added a brief primer at the bottom of the answer, but there is a lot to learn here and you should read more broadly on the topic.

Comment: That... is a really broad question. Classes are about code structure, and have little to do with calling into another API. But in that case you might store your `client` in the class that contains the methods `add_job` and `remove_job`. I'm not clear entirely on what is involved, but I recommend you start with something that doesn't rely on an external api.